# Manipulating numerical document value from findById query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to manipulate the numerical value of a document as so, however when I console.log `NewX` it gives me `NaN` rather than the numerical value I am after.

```
var OldX =  await Col.findById(req.params.id, 'X'); 
var NewX = OldX - 6;
console.log(newX);
```

I think this is related to the fact that if I just console.log `Old X` it returns the following

```
{ X: 2.5, _id: 5baa8b1f4ac3b740248g3005 }
```

This makes me think that I am trying to subtract 6 from an object rather than from the numerical value `2.5` in this case. Nonetheless I'm not sure how to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is actually simple and embarrassingly I discovered it moments after asking the question. Changing

```
var NewX = OldX - 6;
```

to

```
var NewX = OldX.X - 6;
```

gives me access to the numerical value rather than the object.